# I can make a command to create a channel but what do i add to set permissions for it as well?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm slowly learning C# via various means and my current project is a discord bot using discord.net
I want to make a commad to create a "private" channel for whoever uses the command to talk to an admin team. So far I have a command that can create the channel and name it, but being new to C# i'm not sure how to handle permissions overwrites.

If possible an example of what may need to be added with a description of how it works would be most aprreciated.
This is the code for the command I have at the moment:

```
        [Command("create-ticket")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageChannels)]
        public async Task CreateChannel()
        {
            var ctx = Context;
            await ctx.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync($"Support-#{TicketNo}");
            await ReplyAsync($"Support-#{TicketNo} channel has been created.");
            Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("F") + " " + ctx.User.Mention + " created a support ticket.");
            TicketNo = TicketNo ++;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify channel properties in `CreateTextChannelAsync` by using the "func" argument after the name. For example:

```cs
List<Overwrite> permissions = new List<Overwrite>
{
    new Overwrite(guild.EveryoneRole.Id, PermissionTarget.Role,
        new OverwritePermissions(viewChannel: PermValue.Deny)),
    new Overwrite(yourRoleId, PermissionTarget.Role,
        new OverwritePermissions(viewChannel: PermValue.Allow))
};
await guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("Name", x => x.PermissionOverwrites = permissions);
```

Other properties can also be specified here such as the channel topic and category.

If you ever need to change these properties, you can use channel.ModifyAsync(func) in the same way.

[Docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketGuild_CreateTextChannelAsync_System_String_System_Action_Discord_TextChannelProperties__Discord_RequestOptions_)